# Ubuntu one didn't accept my email

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one

I wanted to try Ubuntu one to see if it's better than dropbox. So try to create an account. I Used the built in software in 11.04.

it worked fine until I filled my email address. I got the red warning sign saying it was something wrong, but I checked they were the same and everything else was correct. I then tried to use the Ubuntu-one site but that failed as well since the "anti-robot-thing" never showed up!

[image]

I have an Asus 1201n with Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that this is the Ubuntu **single sign-on** service. If you have registered an account on launchpad, the Ubuntu Wiki, or somewhere else the SSO is used, you will have to log in using this account.

I know you're on Launchpad. Most likely you can just log in using those credentials.

Comment: Allan said the same thing, and it works! Thanks

A small **hint** for Ubuntu-one developers: **TELL USS THAT WE ALREADY HAVE AN ACCOUNT, if we are on launchpad or similar!**

I mean come on why do I have to discover it by asking a question about it on google+ or askubuntu?!